# X86 Assembly: comparison between two immediates

Tags: assembly

Is it possible to do comparison between two integer immediates, such as `cmp $1, $2` or `test $1, $2`?

I keep getting error messages from gcc/as, saying "suffix or operands invalid for cmp". The exact line is

```
cmpq $2, $1001
```

Comment: What's the purpose for trying to compare 2 immediates?  Are you trying to force set the flags for some reason?

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch I am working on a compiler backend. If the IR passed to the backend is not fully optimised (e.g. no constant propagation), it seems to be natural for me just to generate a comparison machine code to compare two immediates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

x86 require no matter when one of the operands is a register, so this is impossible.

Suggestion: since it is two immediates and if your code isn't self-modifying, you can base on the result and hand-optimise the remaining code and replace operations that reads the flags with ones that does not appropriately.